# Zephyr AWS IOT Sample Application

Tags: aws-iot, zephyr-rtos

I have an embedded application running on Zephyr OS

I want to push the sensor data on AWS IOT, there is no sample application for AWS in Zephyr, but there are for Azure and Google IOT

Can anyone guide me in writing a sample application using AWS IOT or some reference for it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mqtt_publisher example, enable CONFIG_MQTT_LIB_TLS, load the root ca, the device ca, and the private key, then you should be able to connect to AWS. Also make sure you increase the main stack to 4096 and heap to 70k.